# Woocommerce special encoding for chinese product attribute taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a product in woocommerce that is stored in chinese language,

The product has different color variations, woocommerce seems to `encode` the attribute taxonomy for the color attribute. in a english language product it would simple store the taxonomy as `pa_color` , but in my chinese language product, woocommerce store the taxonomy as `pa_191386aef4bc441e` , the letters and numbers after `pa_` are an `encoded form` of the string `颜色` which translates to color in english, hence the term taxonomy `pa_191386aef4bc441e` simply means `pa_color` in english.

Am trying to figure out how woocommerce encoded the chinese string `颜色` to `191386aef4bc441e` so that i can decode the text back to a valid chinese string, the final goal is to translate the product attributes to english and replace the chinese values with replaced english values.

How did woocommerce encode the product attribute so that i can decode it back to the original string ?

Look at at the picture below, the text pointed to by an arrow is the the chinese string that gets stored as `pa_191386aef4bc441e`
[image]

Below is how the product data looks on the woocommerce database.

The post has an ID of `1347`
[image]

terms

[image]

term relationships
[image]

term taxonomy
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from the same problem
In another language (Hebrew)
But I noticed that if you create the attribute in a programmatic way
Does not have this problem
As for example in this code

```
`<?php
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

  //Create main product
$product = new WC_Product_Variable();

$att_var = array();
//Create the attribute object with name weight
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_id( 0 );
$attribute->set_name( 'weight' );
$attribute->set_options( array(
        '50g',
        '100g',
        '150g'
) );
$attribute->set_position( 0 );
$attribute->set_visible( 1 );
$attribute->set_variation( 1 );
$att_var[] = $attribute;

//Create the attribute object with name brand
$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();
$attribute->set_name( 'חברה' );
$attribute->set_options( array(
        'מרצדס',
        'וולוו'
) );
$attribute->set_position( 1 );
$attribute->set_visible( 1 );
$attribute->set_variation( 1 );
$att_var[] = $attribute;

$product->set_attributes($att_var);
$product->set_name('Product 3');
$product->set_status('publish');
$product->set_sku(12345);

//Save main product to get its id
$product->set_category_ids([47, 56] );
$id = $product->save();

//variation 1
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_regular_price(10);
$variation->set_sale_price(10);
$variation->set_stock_quantity(12);
$variation->set_manage_stock(True);
$variation->set_weight('50g');
$variation->set_parent_id($id);

$variation->set_attributes(array(
        'weight' => '50g',
        'חברה' => 'מרצדס'
));

//Save variation, returns variation id
$variation->save();

//variation 2
$variation_new = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation_new->set_regular_price(15);
$variation_new->set_sale_price(12);
$variation_new->set_stock_quantity(20);
$variation_new->set_manage_stock(True);
$variation_new->set_weight('100g');
$variation_new->set_parent_id($id);

//Set attributes requires a key/value containing
$variation_new->set_attributes(array(
        'weight' => '100g',
        'חברה' => 'וולוו'
));


//Save variation, returns variation id
$variation_new->save();`
```